# Display page until condition is met and then redirect

Tags: php, loops, redirect, conditional-statements

I have a holding page that redirects to another page once that page has been created.

At the moment my solution is to refresh the holding page every 5s, checking each time if the new page has been created.  Problem is that the page flickers.

Is there a way to do this with a simple while loop in the header but still display the holding page html.  Thanks.  Current code is below.

```
<?php
ob_start();
$id = escapeshellarg($_GET['id']);
$id = str_replace("'", "", $id);
$url = 'http://sub.testxxx.com/'. $id . '/index.html';
$handle = @fopen($url,'r');
if(!$handle) {
header("Refresh: 5; url=http://testxxx.com/loading.php?id=".$id);
ob_flush;
} else {
sleep(5);
header("Location: http://sub.testxxx.com/".$id);
}
?>
<html>
...........

</html>
<?
ob_flush;
?>
```

Comment: I would do it as javascript calls instead of php refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

I would split it into two parts: **1)** a server side script (php) checking if the page has been created and **2)** a client side script (javascript) calling the php script via ajax every n-seconds. If the php script returns true, the js redirects the client to its new destination. no need to reload the whole page - and no flickering ;)

Do you need some example code?

Comment: Thanks for your help and kind offer.  I'm pursuing the code suggested by SunnyTar but am running into a problem with the need to pass a php variable into Ajax

Answer (score 0):

checkPage.php:

```
<?php
$id = escapeshellarg($_GET['id']);
$id = str_replace("'", "", $id);
$url = 'http://sub.testxxx.com/'. $id . '/index.html';
$handle = @fopen($url,'r');
if(!$handle) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
?>
```

Page.php:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  url: 'checkPage.php?id=someId',
  success: function(data) {
    $(location).attr('href','http://sub.testxxx.com/someId/index.html');
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have a couple of questions borne out of my ignorance I'm afraid. 1. Will checkpage.php check for the existence of the new page every 5s?  2.  I would like to use page.php?id=xxx  where xxx is the someId variable captured as $id - fyi. the id is put into a database. Is there a way to pass this variable through to Ajax so that checkPage.php?id=$id?

Comment: save "$.ajax..." like finction and call it in cycle every 5 secs. You also can check your db for $id in the begining of Page.php.

Comment: Thanks again for your response.  I've been working on this al day!  I've got the checkpage.php working but am struggling with the php variable within the ajax code.  I've submitted a new question in order to show the edited code if you feel there is any more you can add.  Many thanks. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365355/redirect-page-when-new-page-created-using-php-variable-and-ajax)